# MVC + jQuery: how to create an input text through Html.TextBox() and specifying a "class" attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm trying to create an input text through the following code so it can hold a date that user can choose in a date-picker jQuery control:

```
    <%: Html.TextBox("date", null, new {class = "date-pick"}) %>
        <input name="date" id="date" class="date-pick" />
```

Problem is, I need to specify the "class" attribute for the input text, but "class" is of course a reserved keword in C# :-)

Is there any way to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984.aspx) override for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@class` in cases such as this, it should look like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("date", null, new {@class = "date-pick"}) %>
```

For any attribute that's a reserved word, just prefix it with a `@`.

Comment: Wow, the syntax highlighter even saw the difference

Answer (score 0):

For people lookign to set the value and happen to stumble across this question like I did, the same sort of code from Nick Craver's answer can be applied to setting the value of a text field  too:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => model.Propertyname, new {@Value = "5"})
```

The above must be used instead of the below or it will not work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => model.Propertyname, new {@Value = "5"})
```

You must also use a capital 'v' for `Value`